# How to get current date and time with respect to Time Zone in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I run the following code in codeigniter, it returns incorrect time and date for the India location. Please let me the solution.

```
'date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
echo $date;'
```

Comment: show your output and what your desired output?

Comment: No it doesn't, `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');$date = new DateTime();var_dump( $date );` and `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); echo $date;` both show the same time as http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india/kolkata .  Do you have a timezone set in you php.ini file that may be over riding your code?

Comment: Your code is normal php code only. And its works fine. can you please check the default timezone in `php.ini` file

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```